# Transform LINQ IQueryable into a paged IQueryable using LINQ to NHibernate

Tags: linq, nhibernate, paging, expression

I wanna do something like that

```
    public IQueryable GetPaged<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> query, int startIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        return GetSession()
          .Linq<TSource>()
          .UseQuery(query)
          .Take(pageSize)
          .Skip(startIndex);
    }
```

So you can put **any** IQuerable statement and "it becomes paged" or it will be paged.

I am using LINQ to NHibernate.
I hope you get it, sry for this bad english :o

edit: Maybe my approach is the wrong one, is it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is copied from working code:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{   
    public static IQueryable<T> Paged<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, int page,
                                                                    int pageSize)
    {
        return source
          .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
          .Take(pageSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: sry this is not what I wanted. I want to create an IQuerable object. This object shall be passed into the method GetAllPaged(IQuerable queryThatShallbePaged, int pageSize, int startIndex)

Comment: Rename the variable names and you have what you say.

Comment: your solution is used by the client and the client has not to put the query in the method, because of the Linq Extension Method. I wanted to have a solution for my repositories. But yes your solution works, but it is not exactly what I want. I dont want this ... IQueryable.Paged(page, size) I want this ... Paged(query, page, size). But I am not sure what solution is better.

Comment: I use my solution in the repository. I don't understand what you mean. Is C# a new language for you?

Comment: I think you dont get me. I am new to Linq/Linq extension methods. Can you post your repository method?

Comment: I'm not going to explain my whole repository to explain extension methods. Please google it or ask a specific question on stack overflow.

Comment: The above code sample would not compile for me because T was unknown. I had to change it to Paged<T>(...

Answer (score 0):

```
return query.skip(startIndex).take(pageSize);
```

Comment: The Problem is that I use LINQ to NHibernate and GetSession().Linq<T>() is of Type IQueryable/IQueryable<T> so this does not help me