# Paging Extension Method for IQueryable(Of T)

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, extension-methods, iqueryable

I have written the following method attempting to extend `IQueryable<T>` to provide generic paging that integrates with my custom pager control. But, when I attempt to call the method on an `IQueryable<Account>`, I get the following Compiler Error:

> BC30456: 'Page' is not a member of 'System.Linq.IQueryable(Of
>   OrgName.ProjName.Account)'.

Source:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module Paging
    <Extension()>
    Public Function Page(Of T)(source As IQueryable(Of T), pageIndex As Integer, pageSize As Integer, ByRef recordCount As Integer) As IQueryable(Of T)
        recordCount = source.Count()
        Return source.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
    End Function
End Module
```

The module file is in the same assembly and namespace as the `Account` business object (`OrgName.ProjName`).  (Names have been changed to protect the innocent.)

I'm not sure how the above is any different than the accepted answer in this question (other than language, obviously):
[Transform LINQ IQueryable into a paged IQueryable using LINQ to NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035028/transform-linq-iqueryable-into-a-paged-iqueryable-using-linq-to-nhibernate)

**Any idea what I'm doing wrong?**

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but are you referencing Paging in the class that uses this?

Comment: @DanDrews As far as I can tell, yes.  It's on an ASP.NET page.  I can use `Account` in the same line of code, and as I mentioned, the module is in the same assembly as `Account`.  I have a project reference to the assembly (a class library project) and I import its namespace in the root web.config of that ASP.NET Web Site project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your module is Public, and also make sure to use the appropriate "Imports" statement in the file where you want to use the extension method.

Cheers

Comment: Wow, I added `Public` and everything works great.  Thanks for the fix, boy I feel kinda dumb now.  This MSDN article is what led me astray with a flawed example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx

Comment: @thepirat000, and how exactly would that help?

Comment: @thepirat000 and what does this have to do with the original question ?

Comment: No need to clutter the question further, please.  If you find a comment unconstructive, just flag it as such.

Comment: To add more detail to this, the default access level for a `Module` declaration is `Friend`.  Since my module was in a separate assembly from where it was being used, `Friend` did not give enough access so `Public` had to be used.